# Can a barbarian take both a totem and a blood rage powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

Simply put it says for for totems you cannot take a different type of totem. For blood rage powers it says you cannot take a different type of blood rage power. However I can't find anything preventing or approving of a barbarian taking both blood and totem rage powers?

Ex. A barbarian takes Spirit totem rage powers but on other levels takes Elemental blood rage powers?

Just an example not my exact intentions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you do not take more than one different totem and more than one different bloodrage power, it appears you can in fact do both. From the SRD:

> A totem rage power cannot be selected from more than one group of *totem rage powers*; for example, a character who selects a beast totem rage power cannot later choose to gain a dragon totem rage power.

and

> A barbarian cannot select from more than one group of *blood rage powers*. A barbarian of any level can take a lesser blood rage power.

So you can pick and stay with one thematic totem power set and one thematic bloodrage power set without issue, since the rules only specify them as exclusive within their own groups.

Comment: Thanks I figured as much going by those text but I wanted to see if someone had dug up an FAQ or something that might of contradicted it. (Will wait a day for other responses before I close with accepted answer)